# SSH - fingerprint variation

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to SSH in to one of my servers. Should the RSA fingerprint be the same no matter which of the server's IP addresses I use to connect, or will it be different for each?

Comment: Unless you run multiple sshd instances...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should always be the same, and it should match what is returned from `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

Answer (score 1):

If you specify:

```
VisualHostkey yes
```

In your ssh client configuration (if you are using openssh client), you will see a graphical rendering of the fingerprint. This should make it easier/faster to compare visually then comparing a string of hex-digits.

But yeah, as stated before, the key/fingerprint is independant of the ip-adres or port-number.
Though if you are hosting multiple ssh-installs (or using redirects on the network) you could see different fingerprints on the different ports.